# Add new line when printing C# string array

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a c# winforms app that allows users to select / print rows from a `DataGridView`. I can't work out how to create a new line for each row. I have found a few answers for similar questions but none that work for me.

```
private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    Graphics graphic = ev.Graphics;
    DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
    {
        DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
        string myStr = string.Join( "|", myRow.ItemArray.Select( p => p.ToString( ) ).ToArray( ));
        //myStr += "/n/r"; 
        graphic.DrawString(myStr, new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 20, 225);
    }
}
```

Everything I try just concatenates on to my string

Comment: Alternatively each line has its own `DrawString()` statement while increasing the `y` location according to `graphic.MeasureString(...).Height`.

Comment: Or draw the text using a layout rectangle and let the system wrap lines to create a paragraph look. It all depends on want the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new line to a string is as simple as

```
myString += Environment.NewLine;
```

However, you will need to make sure that what you're using to display the string correctly renders new lines.